# summarizing the proportion of records in each row of dataframe

Tags: r, row, summary

I have large dataframe which has some columns with only 'NA' values. I want to summarize each row in term of percentage.
let's say: df

```
user col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
 100   1    1    2   2    1    NA
 200   1    2    3   3    NA   NA
 300   2    3    3   3    2    NA
```

I want to summarize the `user` rows based on the percentage of total members.
for example, user:100 has 3/5 of event 1 and 2/5 event 2.

summarized_df:

```
user event1 event2 event3
100    3/5   2/5    0
200    1/4   1/4    2/4
300    0     2/5    3/5
```

it is also useful to use percentage for each event.
how can I do it in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R method with `apply`, `table`, and `prop.table`.

```
cbind(dat[1],
      prop.table(t(apply(dat[-1], 1,
                   function(x) table(factor(x, levels=1:3)))), 1))
```

`factor` is needed to assure that the output of `table` applied to each row returns every potential element (`1:3`), even if one or more levels is not observed. Here, `apply` runs through all of the rows, and returns counts for each event, including 0s when the event did not occur. Because the output of each call has the same length, `apply` returns a matrix. We transpose the matrix and the use `prop.table` to calculate the the proportion of each event for each row. Finally, `cbind` combines the first column with this matrix returning a data.frame with the desired output.

this returns

```
  user    1    2   3
1  100 0.60 0.40 0.0
2  200 0.25 0.25 0.5
3  300 0.00 0.40 0.6
```

**data**

```
dat <- 
structure(list(user = c(100L, 200L, 300L), col1 = c(1L, 1L, 2L
), col2 = 1:3, col3 = c(2L, 3L, 3L), col4 = c(2L, 3L, 3L), col5 = c(1L, 
NA, 2L), col6 = c(NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("user", "col1", "col2", 
"col3", "col4", "col5", "col6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```

Comment: `dat[1]` returns a data.frame consisting of the first column. `dat[-1]` returns a data.frame consisting of all columns except the first column.

Comment: how can I give it column name (or names) instead of index?for example instead of `dat[c(-1,-5)]` is like `data[-c("user_id","grades")]`.(the last code does not work)

Comment: Your question is not clear. You can assign names with `names(dat) <- c(...)`. You can index using names directly as you note `dat["user"]` instead of `dat[1]`. If you want to remove based on names, you have to do something clever like `dat[setdiff(names(dat), "user")]`, which will drop the first column or `dat[-grep("user", names(dat))]` which will do the same.